# Como poner 2 barras de desplazamiento horizontales en un v-data-table (Vue / vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

lo que pasa es que estoy practicando Vue / Vuetify con las v-data-table, estaba elaborando una tabla y veo que tiene una barra de desplazamiento horizontal pero esta se encuentra en la parte de abajo.

[image: Resultado de mi codigo]

Lo que quiero hacer ahora es tener 2 barras de desplazamiento horizontales, una que este abajo que es la que se crea por default, y otra arriba de la tabla, que ambas funcionen para moverse por la información del v-data-table (Foto editada)

[image: Foto editada de como quisiera hacerlo y funcione]

Intente buscar información pero solo encuentro para JS y html5 vainilla, mas no en Vue / Vuetify

Este es el código que utilizo:

---

```
<template>
  <v-container>

     <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :items-per-page="5"
    class="elevation-1"
  ></v-data-table>

  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'HelloWorld',

    data () {
      return {
        headers: [
          {
            text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
            align: 'start',
            sortable: false,
            value: 'name',
            width: 300
          },
          { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories', width: 300},
          { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat', width: 300 },
          { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs', width: 300 },
          { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein', width: 300 },
          { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron', width: 300 },
        ],
        desserts: [
          {
            name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
            calories: 159,
            fat: 6.0,
            carbs: 24,
            protein: 4.0,
            iron: '1%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
            calories: 237,
            fat: 9.0,
            carbs: 37,
            protein: 4.3,
            iron: '1%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Eclair',
            calories: 262,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 23,
            protein: 6.0,
            iron: '7%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Cupcake',
            calories: 305,
            fat: 3.7,
            carbs: 67,
            protein: 4.3,
            iron: '8%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Gingerbread',
            calories: 356,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 49,
            protein: 3.9,
            iron: '16%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Jelly bean',
            calories: 375,
            fat: 0.0,
            carbs: 94,
            protein: 0.0,
            iron: '0%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Lollipop',
            calories: 392,
            fat: 0.2,
            carbs: 98,
            protein: 0,
            iron: '2%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Honeycomb',
            calories: 408,
            fat: 3.2,
            carbs: 87,
            protein: 6.5,
            iron: '45%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Donut',
            calories: 452,
            fat: 25.0,
            carbs: 51,
            protein: 4.9,
            iron: '22%',
          },
          {
            name: 'KitKat',
            calories: 518,
            fat: 26.0,
            carbs: 65,
            protein: 7,
            iron: '6%',
          },
        ],
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eh podido encontrar un resultado.

Lo que se debe de hacer es generar 3 métodos de CSS, uno para el tamaño de la ruta de la barra de desplazamiento, otro para el tamaño de la barra de desplazamiento y otro para hacer visible y funcional la barra de desplazamiento.

Luego en export default del componente se añade la sección de mounted y se inserta un método, que lo que hace es decirle que la posición de mi barra de desplazamiento de arriba será la misma que la de abajo y viceversa.

Para referenciar la barra de desplazamiento superior utilizo la etiqueta wrapper2, y para referenciar la barra de desplazamiento del v-data-table es necesario hacer 2 referencias, una a la etiqueta con la que se identificara el v-data-table y otra que hace referencia al mismo componente de v-data-table.

Y lo que es el hmtl solo es necesario hacer una referencia entre la barra de desplazamiento y el v-data-table.

[image: Resultado Final]

Esta fue la modificación de código realizada:

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    
    <v-col>
        <!-- we use this wrapper to show the second scroll above of table -->
        <div id="wrapper2">
          <div id="div2" class="width-scroll" >
          </div>
        </div>
    </v-col>
    
<v-col>
     <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :items-per-page="5"
    class="elevation-1 table-reference"
  ></v-data-table>
</v-col>

  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'HelloWorld',

    data () {
      return {
        headers: [
          {
            text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
            align: 'start',
            sortable: false,
            value: 'name',
            width: 300
          },
          { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories', width: 300},
          { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat', width: 300 },
          { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs', width: 300 },
          { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein', width: 300 },
          { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron', width: 300 },
        ],
        desserts: [
          {
            name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
            calories: 159,
            fat: 6.0,
            carbs: 24,
            protein: 4.0,
            iron: '1%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
            calories: 237,
            fat: 9.0,
            carbs: 37,
            protein: 4.3,
            iron: '1%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Eclair',
            calories: 262,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 23,
            protein: 6.0,
            iron: '7%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Cupcake',
            calories: 305,
            fat: 3.7,
            carbs: 67,
            protein: 4.3,
            iron: '8%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Gingerbread',
            calories: 356,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 49,
            protein: 3.9,
            iron: '16%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Jelly bean',
            calories: 375,
            fat: 0.0,
            carbs: 94,
            protein: 0.0,
            iron: '0%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Lollipop',
            calories: 392,
            fat: 0.2,
            carbs: 98,
            protein: 0,
            iron: '2%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Honeycomb',
            calories: 408,
            fat: 3.2,
            carbs: 87,
            protein: 6.5,
            iron: '45%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Donut',
            calories: 452,
            fat: 25.0,
            carbs: 51,
            protein: 4.9,
            iron: '22%',
          },
          {
            name: 'KitKat',
            calories: 518,
            fat: 26.0,
            carbs: 65,
            protein: 7,
            iron: '6%',
          },
        ],
      }
    },
    
    mounted(){
      let wrapper_1 = document.querySelector('.table-reference .v-data-table__wrapper');
      let wrapper_2 = document.querySelector('#wrapper2');
      wrapper_1.onscroll = function() {
        wrapper_2.scrollLeft = wrapper_1.scrollLeft;
      };
        
      wrapper_2.onscroll = function() {
        wrapper_1.scrollLeft = wrapper_2.scrollLeft;
      };
    },

  }
</script>

<style>

/* Este es el tamaño de la ruta de la barra de desplazamiento */
#wrapper2{
      width: 100%;
      overflow-x: scroll; 
      overflow-y:hidden;
  }

/* Este div permite hacer la funcion de desplazamiento y muestra la barra de desplazamiento */
  #div2 {
      height: 1px;
      overflow: scroll;
  }

  /* Este es el tamaño de la barra de desplazamiento */
  .width-scroll{
    width:1800px;
  }

</style>
```